Setting up the authorization for AWS Step function using serverless framework
serverless.yaml
This is my serverless.yaml file for AWS Step function.
This step function is working very well without authorizer property.
But I need to set up the authorizer. so if I add the authorizer on step function, I can't get the token like second image.
submitQuestionnaire.ts
So how can I solve this issue?
So to solve this issue, I tried to fix the serverless yaml file following this link.
https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-step-functions
So I fixed the serverless yaml file like these images.
serverless yaml 1
serverless yaml 2
And I tried to deploy it on AWS environment.
But I got this error message.
error message
